# "IntelliTrace debugging not available" error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

In XP 32bit Visual Studio 2010 I get the error below when I start debugging with IntelliTrace enabled. Doesn't IntelliTrace work in Windows XP or is there some setting which causes this error?

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/28lum3p.jpg]

**UPDATE:**
The error occurs when I choose the second option to add call information in the IntelliTrace settings. There's nothing in the event log about this error. The question now is how to find out why VS is having trouble adding call information.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

IntelliTrace works on Windows XP it just does not support collecting event and call information with IIS 5. The supported versions of IIS are 6.0, 7.0 and 7.5. Those versions are installed on Windows 2003, Windows 2008 and Windows 2008 R2, respectively.